# Resetting Mountain Lion iCloud login request

Tags: macos, icloud, accounts

The first time you log into a new account with Mountain Lion, a special iCloud login screen is shown. Once you "skip" this screen it is never shown again.

When setting up an account I like to add a few things (like a welcome note of my own). But I'd also like to leave the iCloud login screen intact for the first time the intended user logs in.

Is there any way to reset this login screen so that it will be presented on the next attempt to login to a given account?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is add some files to the user's desktop or documents folder, you can create the account in system preferences, then add these files to the relevant directories by navigating to the user's home folder in Finder ( /Users//Desktop ) without logging in at all. The user will then be prompted to setup iCloud the first time they log in.

Comment: Chris, that's not a bad workaround and I may use it. Thanks! Just a few surmountable permissions issues. But I am still curious about whether there is a way to reset the iCloud login request.